# Post soap envelope from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, soap

How would I post the following soap envelope via a bash script.

In PHP I would post using cURL but don't know how to translate into bash?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <env:Header>
    <n:Request xmlns:n="http://www.****.com/iprs/soap" env:role="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/role/ultimateReceiver" env:mustUnderstand="true">UserMod</n:Request>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <n:RequestUserMod xmlns:n="http://www.****.com/iprs/soap">
      <n:UserID>****</n:UserID>
      <n:UserData >
        <n:SystemName>****</n:SystemName>
        <n:AdminState>enabled</n:AdminState>
        <n:CategoryTypeID>****</n:CategoryTypeID>
        <n:Permissions>****</n:Permissions>
        <n:BillingProgID>****</n:BillingProgID>
        <n:DefaultGroupID>****</n:DefaultGroupID>
        <n:PrimarySiteID>****</n:PrimarySiteID>
        <n:SecondarySiteID>****</n:SecondarySiteID>
        <n:ContactInfo></n:ContactInfo>
        <n:Password>****</n:Password>
      </n:UserData>
    </n:RequestUserMod>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

If possible I would also like to detect the response, which should be:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type:application/soap+xml; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length:509

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><env:Header>
<n:Response xmlns:n="http://www.*****.com/iprs/soap" env:role="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/role/ultimateReceiver" env:mustUnderstand="true">UserMod</n:Response>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
<n:ResponseUserMod xmlns:n="http://www.*****.com/iprs/soap">
<n:StatusReport>
<n:Code>ok</n:Code>
<n:SubCode>0</n:SubCode>
</n:StatusReport>
</n:ResponseUserMod>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: For starters, you need a command-line tool that can do HTTP.  Try "wget".  http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps like this?

```
curl --data - --request "POST" "http://www.somesite.com" <<EOF

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <env:Header>
    <n:Request xmlns:n="http://www.****.com/iprs/soap" env:role="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/role/ultimateReceiver" env:mustUnderstand="true">UserMod</n:Request>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <n:RequestUserMod xmlns:n="http://www.****.com/iprs/soap">
      <n:UserID>****</n:UserID>
      <n:UserData >
        <n:SystemName>****</n:SystemName>
        <n:AdminState>enabled</n:AdminState>
        <n:CategoryTypeID>****</n:CategoryTypeID>
        <n:Permissions>****</n:Permissions>
        <n:BillingProgID>****</n:BillingProgID>
        <n:DefaultGroupID>****</n:DefaultGroupID>
        <n:PrimarySiteID>****</n:PrimarySiteID>
        <n:SecondarySiteID>****</n:SecondarySiteID>
        <n:ContactInfo></n:ContactInfo>
        <n:Password>****</n:Password>
      </n:UserData>
    </n:RequestUserMod>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>

EOF
```

Comment: keep getting 500 Internal server error, but same data from curl in my php class is 200 OK.. strange

Comment: Well, I do not know that much about curl...  You can always look at the tcp transcript in wireshark

Comment: replace with a : `cat file | curl ....` : the <<EOF method may interpret the content (ie, replace any "$something" with the value of variable something (or '' if undefined), etc.)

Comment: @OlivierDulac: I thought that to be an advantage. Then he can put  values in the variables and send a "dynamic" request, instead always the same...

Comment: could be either an advantage, or a drawback (as everything needs to be checked to avoid having bad side effects)... depends on the content (and on the knowledge the person have of every possible contents)

Answer (score 0):

to post:

```
cat file | curl ...
```

but to retrieve the result, and act according to it, embed it all in a `expect` script.